# How to efficiently get an array of values from a referenced hash and an array of keys in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I currently have an referenced hash and an array of keys that the hash contains. I want to get an array of the values corresponding to my array of keys.

I know how to do this in multiple lines:

```
# Getting hash reference and array of keys.
my $hashRef = {
    one   => 'foo',
    two   => 'bar',
    three => 'baz'
};
my @keys = ('one', 'three');

# Getting corresponding array of values.
my @values;
foreach my $key (@keys) {
    push @values, $hashRef->{$key};
}
```

However, I believe that there must be a much better way that doesn't make use of a loop. But unfortunately I just can't figure it out. How can I efficiently 
get an array of values from a referenced hash and an array of keys; ideally in one line if possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easily:

```
my @values = @$hashRef{@keys};
```

Or, on Perl 5.24+:

```
my @values = $hashRef->@{@keys};
```

Or, on Perl 5.20+ by enabling some additional features:

```
use feature qw(postderef);
no warnings qw(experimental::postderef);

my @values = $hashRef->@{@keys};
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you can get the values for multiple keys (a "slice") of a `%hash` with the `@hash{LIST}` syntax. You just have to dereference it first. See [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) for more information.

Comment: Would this work the same? I prefer to use arrow notation: @{ $hashRef->{@keys} }

Comment: Ah I see, but this will still be equivalent right: @{ $hashRef }{@keys}

Comment: Yup. You've got it.